# Why do i get e^x log(e) when i try to differentiate e^x on maxima?

Tags: math, maxima

When I input `"diff(e^x,x);"` into Maxima, what I get in return is `"e^x log(e)"`.

What can I do to get the correct answer? (just e^x)

Comment: Technically it's already the correct answer ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I always thought e^x was it's own derivative.

Comment: you'll probably have to add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanielCorrea: It is.  But log(e) == 1...

Answer (score 3):

You have to use %e, otherwise Maxima thinks that e is a random constant.